# Init in Swift language

Tags: swift, initialization, init

I read that

> init

in Swift does not return value, then why i can write this :

```
var str = String.init("mystring")
```

Comment: Strictly spoken *does not return value* is wrong. The `init` function does return the instance but you must not return `self` explicitly like in Objective-C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function init doesn't return you are right, but in this case, you are just making a variable equal the struct String which is initialised with "hello"

It is the same as:

```
var class = someClass()
```

The () is an init function with no arguments.

Comment: thanks, сan you  give please other example  of use of init when it doesn't return value?

Comment: Pretty much any time you see () on something that isn't a function it is an init call. So for example AVAudioPlayer() or even [String]()

Comment: In these cases you need to assign the initialised instance to a variable or it has no where to stay in memory. the variable IS the instance of the class or object etc, the init call has not returned anything.